# Plotting data from MySQL with FLOT and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, flot

I would like to use AJAX with FLOT in order to chart some data from a MySQL database.  I wrote the code below to get the data from the database and plot using FLOT, but something is not working correctly.  Any assistance with making this work is appreciated.

```
<?php

require 'database_connect.php';

try
{
$sql = "SELECT ts, COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE time IS NOT NULL and ts > ( NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'databaseQuery.php - Database access failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
include 'error.html.php';
exit();
}

while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
$five_mins[] = $row;
}

include 'databaseQuery.html.php';

$pdo = null; // Disconnect from the database server.

?>
```

The database query correctly pulls from my database a UTC timestamp as element 0 and an integer as element 1.

In order to display the numbers in a web page, I use the brief code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Real-Time Metrics</title>
 </head>

  <?php
    foreach ($five_mins as $fm):
    echo "<p>Here are the results for 5 minutes of actions 0: " . $fm[0] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Here are the results for 5 minutes of actions 1: " . $fm[1] . "</p>";
  ?>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

</html>
```

I have attempted to plot the data using the code below:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Real-Time Metrics</title>

  <link href="css/flot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/jshashtable-3.0.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.numberformatter-1.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.symbol.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>

<script>

// Options for plotting
          var options = {
           series: {
            lines: {
             show: true,
             lineWidth: 1.2,
             fill: true
            }
           },
           xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            tickSize: ["2", "second"],
            tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
             var date = new Date(v);
             if (date.getSeconds() % 20 == 0) {
              var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
              var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
              var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
              return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
             } else {
              return "";
             }
            },
           axisLabel: "Local Time",
           axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
           axisLabelFontSizePixels: 14,
           axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
           axisLabelPadding: 10
           },
           yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            tickSize: 5,
            tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
             if (v % 10 == 0) {
              return v;
             } else {
              return "";
             }
            },
            axisLabel: "Actions",
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 14,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 6
           },
           legend: {
            labelBoxBorderColor: "#fff"
           },
          };

// End of the plot options

// Begin plot

 $(document).ready(function(){
  var callAjax = function(){
   $.ajax({
    method:'get',
    url:'php/databaseQuery.php',
    cache: false,
    success:function(results){
     dataset = [{ label: "ACTIONS", data: results }];
     $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, options);
    }
   });
  }
  callAjax();
  setInterval(callAjax,3000);
 });
</script>

<body>
<div id="header">
 <h2>Real-time Metrics</h2>
</div>
 <div id="content">
  <div class="container">
   <div id="placeholder" class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **but something is not working correctly** well that narrows it down

Comment: In your AJAX success handler show us what `results` resolves to. Can't answer this question without seeing an example of your data. At a quick glance your datetimes don't look to be epoch milliseconds but seconds, try `SELECT ts * 1000`.

Comment: Dagon - I appreciate you taking the time to read through my question, however, your response is not helpful.  Please limit your response to something that will further the issue, not just criticize.

Comment: Mark - Thank you for your help!  The data comes from a MySQL database where the first column (ts) is a UNIX timestamp created by MySQL when a row changes.  The second piece of data is an integer.